# Android Keystore add key

Tags: android, security, keystore

So I'm developing an android app which connects to a Restful API. I want to add a checksumm to each call to authenticate it. For that, I need a private key on server and App. 
After searching for some time, it seems that the KeyStore is the only option where a key can be stored safely. But I can't find an example of how to add a custom key and call it in the app. Can someone provide a complete example?

Comment: Android is *not really* secure. Keys on your phone will not add much security. You can see how to check API calls in this [Google Blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Android KeyStore is actually quite secure on devices with a hardware-backed keystore (which is most all of them released in the last 2-3 years, and all of them launched with Android M or later).  Keys generated with Android KeyStore are stored in and never leave secure hardware, so the key material is inaccessible even if the kernel is compromised. You can also add various access control requirements to limit how/when the key can be used, such as only within a specified time after the user has authenticated.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but what did you exactly mean by "storing _custom_ key"?

Comment: are we thinking of the same here - putting a specific string into keyStore?